# Calculating the gene overlap between different gene lists as a %

Tags: r, rstudio

I have generated a table to show the overlap between different gene lists. Since I have eight different gene lists I have 64 results. The code I currently have is as follows:

```
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Set the working directory and load the data files
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
setwd("~/Desktop/R_Project/Gene_overlap")
getwd()
files <- list.files(pattern="*.txt", full.names = TRUE)
files

data.list <- lapply(files, function(fil) {
  scan(file=fil, what=character())
})

names(data.list) <- basename(files) %>% stringr::str_remove("\\.txt$")

str(data.list)
# List of 8
# $ GSE108363_BCGdown_D: chr [1:350] "IL1B" "IL6" "IL1A" "CCL20" ...
# $ GSE108363_BCGdown_V: chr [1:267] "IL6" "CCL20" "IL1A" "CXCL5" ...
# $ GSE108363_BCGup_D  : chr [1:250] "FABP4" "CMTM2" "FUCA1" "CD36" ...
# $ GSE108363_BCGup_V  : chr [1:429] "FCN1" "FCGR3B" "MNDA" "CPVL" ...
# $ GSE108363_MTBdown_D: chr [1:86] "CCL20" "IL1B" "IL1A" "IL6" ...
# $ GSE108363_MTBdown_V: chr [1:244] "IL1B" "IL1A" "CCL20" "IL6" ...
# $ GSE108363_MTBup_D  : chr [1:128] "FUCA1" "FGL2" "TGFBI" "CPVL" ...
# $ GSE108363_MTBup_V  : chr [1:286] "FABP4" "RNASE1" "MNDA" "CPVL" ...

intersect(data.list$GSE108363_BCGdown_D, data.list$GSE108363_BCGdown_V) %>% length

sapply(data.list, length)



#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Using the intersect function to see the overlaps 
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

data.file1 <- "GSE108363_BCGdown_V.txt"
data.file2 <- "GSE108363_BCGdown_D.txt"
data.file3 <- "GSE108363_BCGup_V.txt"
data.file4 <- "GSE108363_BCGup_D.txt"
data.file5 <- "GSE108363_MTBdown_V.txt"
data.file6 <- "GSE108363_MTBdown_D.txt"
data.file7 <- "GSE108363_MTBup_V.txt"
data.file8 <- "GSE108363_MTBup_D.txt"

genevect1 <- scan(data.file1, what=character(), sep="\n")
genevect2 <- scan(data.file2, what=character(), sep="\n")
genevect3 <- scan(data.file3, what=character(), sep="\n")
genevect4 <- scan(data.file4, what=character(), sep="\n")
genevect5 <- scan(data.file5, what=character(), sep="\n")
genevect6 <- scan(data.file6, what=character(), sep="\n")
genevect7 <- scan(data.file7, what=character(), sep="\n")
genevect8 <- scan(data.file8, what=character(), sep="\n")


filelist <- list(data.file1, data.file2, data.file3, data.file4, data.file5, data.file6, data.file7, data.file8)
all(sapply(filelist, file.exists))

# read files:
gene.lists <- lapply(filelist, function(f) {
  scan(file=f, what=character())
})


# set up empty matrix
x <- (length(gene.lists))^2
x
y <- rep(NA, x)
mx <- matrix(y, ncol=length(gene.lists))
mx
row.names(mx) <- sapply(filelist, basename) %>% stringr::str_remove('.txt$')
colnames(mx) <- sapply(filelist, basename) %>% stringr::str_remove('.txt$')
mx

mx.overlap.count <- mx

# seq_along(gene.lists) # 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
for (i in seq_along(gene.lists)) {
  g1 <- gene.lists[[i]]
  for (j in seq_along(gene.lists)) {
    g2 <- gene.lists[[j]]
    a <- intersect(g1, g2)
    b <- length(a)
    mx.overlap.count[j,i] <- b
  }
}

mx.overlap.count
View(mx.overlap.count)
```

I would now like to do something similar but instead of viewing the overlap as numbers, I would like to see the extent to which overlaps exist between different gene lists **as a percentage**. Somehow i will need to see whether g1 or g2 is greater in order to divide b by the larger one before multiplying by 100. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Define gene overlap.

Comment: genes that are common in both lists (comparing two lists a a time)

Answer (score 2):

using a letter sample as you did not provide the genes list:

```
set.seed(1)
data.list <- lapply(sample(10:20), function(n)LETTERS[sample(1:26, n)])

overlaps <- sapply(data.list, function(g1) 
  sapply(data.list, function(g2)
  {round(length(intersect(g1, g2)) / length(g2) * 100)}))

overlaps
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11]
 [1,]  100   50   67   75   42   92   58   92   67    33    92
 [2,]   46  100   62   69   54   77   62   69   69    54    62
 [3,]   53   53  100   60   33   73   60   73   80    33    60
 [4,]   53   53   53  100   47   71   53   76   53    29    82
 [5,]   45   64   45   73  100   91   64   82   36    45    73
 [6,]   61   56   61   67   56  100   56   89   56    33    72
 [7,]   50   57   64   64   50   71  100   86   71    50    64
 [8,]   55   45   55   65   45   80   60  100   60    40    80
 [9,]   50   56   75   56   25   62   62   75  100    38    69
[10,]   40   70   50   50   50   60   70   80   60   100    70
[11,]   58   42   47   74   42   68   47   84   58    37   100
```

(I used `set.seed` so you can reproduce the example). It uses a nested sapply to iterate over both gene lists individually and then calculates the percentage for each combination of gene vectors, by dividing the length of the intersect by the total length of the second gene vector. If you want to divide by the length of the longest of the 2 gene vectors, replace `length(g2)` by `max(length(g1), length(g2))`

Comment: @user2974951: good point, but AFAIK, that is not possible because mapply iterates over the lists in parallel, whereas here we need to iterate over the lists individually from eachother.

Comment: @MartijnVanAttekum Thank you so much for your response. This is exactly what I was after. Could I please just ask why the sample is (10:20)?

Comment: Hi @HibaAl-khaffaji `10:20` randomly determines the length of the letter samples that are generated (one of the samples will be length 10, one will 11, etc). No particular reason to choose these numbers, just wanted to have some variation in length.