# Find gene overlap as a percentage between lists

Tags: r, overlap

This question is a variant of the question found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53611397/calculating-the-gene-overlap-between-different-gene-lists-as-a).

I also want to evaluate the percent of gene overlap, but instead of doing a pairwise comparison of all-by-all within a single list, I want to compare one list to a different list set. The original post answer gave an elegant nested sapply, which I don't think will work in my case.

Here are some example data.

```r
>listOfGenes1 <- list("cellLine1" = c("ENSG001", "ENSG002", "ENSG003"), "cellLine2" = c("ENSG003", "ENSG004"), "cellLine3" = c("ENSG004", "ENSG005"))
>myCellLine <- list("myCellLine" = c("ENSG001", "ENSG002", "ENSG003"))
```

I want to compare each of the cell lines in listOfGenes1 to the single group in myCellLine, with output something like:

```r
>overlaps
cellLine1   cellLine2   cellLine3
      100          33           0
```

To be clear, I would like percent overlap, with "myCellLine" as the denominator. Here is what I was trying so far that didn't work out.

```r
overlaps <- sapply(listOfGenes1, function(g1) {round(length(intersect(g1, myCellLine)) / length(myCellLine) * 100)})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try,

```
round(sapply(listOfGenes1, function(i)
                100 * length(intersect(i, myCellLine[[1]])) / length(myCellLine[[1]])), 0)

#cellLine1 cellLine2 cellLine3 
#      100        33         0
```

**NOTE:** Your `myCellLine` object is a list, hence `length(myCellLine)` will not work

Answer (score 1):

We can use `sapply`

```
sapply(listOfGenes1, function(x) mean(myCellLine[[1]] %in% x) * 100)

#cellLine1 cellLine2 cellLine3 
#100.00000  33.33333   0.00000
```

Comment: This works, but what is the purpose of taking the mean?

Comment: @strugglebus we are taking `mean` of logical values which will give you ratio directly.